# onclick= return window.confirm not working in a concatenate php string

Tags: javascript, php

this is my permière question about this forum, I hope to find one from my problem
    I can not display the message of "retrun.windows.confirm share (" blah blah blah ")"
      for information when I remove the message popup confirmation appears.

Here is the code I use

```
$msg=$msg .'
<tr>
            <td>'.$row["Lib_Fr"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["Lib_En"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["Lib_Es"].'</td>
<td > <a class="image_sup" href="bo-gestion-contenu.php?id_LigneSup='.$row['_ID'].'&Table='.$_SESSION['NomTable2'].'" onclick="return window.confirm("dd");">
                                                  <img height="15" border="0" width="14" src="design/ico-delete.gif"/>
                                                  </a>
        <a class="mouse" onclick="SimpleModal.open("Contenu_Maj.php?ID=".$row["_ID"]."&Table=".$_SESSION["NomTable2"]."", 350, 500);" >
                                                  <img height="15" border="0" width="14" src="design/detailed.png"/>
                                                  </a>
        </td>
        </tr>';
```

Comment: Try `return window.confirm(\'dd\');`

Comment: May I suggest *not* using `onclick` attributes?  You should be binding your events using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Comment: Also, what *exactly* are you trying to do?  What do you want to with the return value of `confirm()`?  I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

a class="mouse" onclick="SimpleModal.open("Contenu_Maj.php?ID=".$row["_ID"]."&Table=".$_SESSION["NomTable2"]."", 350, 500);"

you suppose to use apostrophe to concatenate php values here

PS: sorry im on mobile and i dont have wysiwyg editor available